# ActiveX bug in ctlinplc.cpp

Tags: c++, mfc, activex

I am writing an ActiveX Control. Everything worked fine when i test my AX Control with TestConn. But when i put it into a HTML and load the problem happened. When i click on the frame contain my control at the second time, bug occured. It said that "Debug Assertion Failed ..... ctlinplc.cpp line 51).
When i take a look at ctlinplc.cpp the bug line is 
   `ASSERT(m_menuWidths.width[5] == 0);`
Please , tell me how to overcome this bug. P/S: I am also stucking in create an ActiveX Control that has a menubar to add to my website

Comment: what is the value of m_menuWidths.width[5]?

Comment: Sorry but i have no way to debug an activeX control ...